# How to remove filename from path in Windows File Filter Driver?

Tags: c, windows, file, filter, driver

I can get full filename image in my File Filter Driver by:

```
UNICODE_STRING fi = FltObjects->FileObject->FileName
```

so , filename will be like:

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume5\tests\myfile.txt
```

I want to remove myfile.txt from fileName.So fi must have only path:

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume5\tests\
```

How to do that?

Comment: found last \ symbol and change length of `UNICODE_STRING`

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/subauth/ns-subauth-unicode_string), `UNICODE_STRING` is a structure including the length of the wide string (`Length`), the memory allocated to the string (`MaximumLength`), and the pointer to the actual wide string itself (`Buffer`). So I reckon you can do this:

```
if (fi.Length > 0)
{
    PWSTR ptr = fi.Buffer;
    ptr += fi.Length - 1;
    // Scan backwards
    int i;
    while(*ptr != '\\' && ptr != fi.Buffer)
    {
        *ptr = '\0'; // Clear the filename
    }
}
```

to manipulate the `UNICODE_STRING` so that it does not contain the filename.

Comment: Unfortunately , this code not worked and 'while' loop cause hanging windows!.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It should be `fi.Buffer` and `fi.Length`, as `fi` is a structure, not a pointer to a structrure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All.
Finally I wrote suitable & Driver Model Safe code for my question:

```
UNICODE_STRING GetPathOnly(UNICODE_STRING str)
{
    USHORT i = 0;
    if (str.Length > 0)
    {
        for (i = str.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (str.Buffer[i] == L'\\')
            {
                str.Length = (i+1)*2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```